# How to get width of input text (not input box)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, input

I want to know the width of the actual text in the input box, not the input box. Is there an equivalent of

```
$('#mybox').val().width();
```

that measures exactly how many pixels the text takes up? (This code obviously would not work.)

Comment: Have you tried putting the text in an invisible element and measuring that?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this

```
$('input').on('keyup', function() {
    var el = $('<div />', {
        text : this.value, 
        css  : {display : 'table-cell'}
    }).appendTo('body');

    var computedStyle = typeof this.currentStyle != 'undefined' ? 
            this.currentStyle : 
            document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(this, null);

    $.each(computedStyle, function(_, style) {
        if (style.indexOf('display') == -1 && style.indexOf('width') == -1)
            el.get(0).style[style] = computedStyle[style];
    });

    var w = el.prop('clientWidth');
    $(el).remove()

    $('#width_output').html(w + 'px')
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/qE4B9/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Got this from here: [Calculate text width with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/118241/calculate-text-width-with-javascript)

```
String.prototype.width = function(font) {
  var f = font || '12px arial',
      o = $('<div>' + this + '</div>')
            .css({'position': 'absolute', 'float': 'left', 'white-space': 'nowrap', 'visibility': 'hidden', 'font': f})
            .appendTo($('body')),
      w = o.width();

  o.remove();

  return w;
}
```

Now you can use:

```
$('#mybox').val().width();
```